# Rewriting file using O_TRUNC

Tags: c, file

I need to read the contents of a binary file into a buffer, perform an operation on that buffer, than to rewrite the contents of that same file with the output buffer.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
char  in[BUFFSIZE],
     out[BUFFSIZE];

void main(char argc, char **argv)
{
    int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int size = read(file, in, BUFFSIZE);
    hash(in, out, size);
    close(file);
    file = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY, O_TRUNC);
    write(file, out, size);
    close(file);
}
```

If I open the file using `O_RDWR`, and then use `write()`, my output buffer is appended to the end of the file. If I close and re-open the file with `O_TRUNC`, it does not truncate it - output buffer is smaller than the input, so the remnant of the old content can be seen at the end of the file. On the other hand, using `O_WRONLY` makes a file to which I do not have permission to write. I know how to do this using `fopen()` and `fprintf()`, but I would like to avoid that, and, if possible avoid unnecessary closing (use some sort of rewind).

Comment: I think what you would want to do is to use lseek to position the file pointer at start of the file when rewriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second open call to

```
file = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
```

and I think you will get what you want.

BTW, you should check return results from things like open, read, write and close.

Comment: Don't forget the mode.

Comment: Only required for O_CREAT

Comment: Oh yes, probably a DOS habit. IIRC you couldn't separate O_CREAT and write.